# Programming for "no data found"

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA.  I need to enter a number in text box and search spreadsheet for that number and then return the data in columns beside the found number in text boxes in form. I have done this but the question I have is how to write an exception if the number is not found?

Comment: If memory serves, Excel will automatically stick something in the cell that indicates this.

Comment: If you show some of your code someone might be able to tell you how to modify it to get the result you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Like so. *Assumptions made for sheet name, range name, textbox name, etc. Solely done for illustrative purposes to show you how to go about it*:

```
Sub FindNumber()

Dim myNum

myNum = TextBox1.Value

Dim rng as Range

Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A100").Find(myNum,lookat:xlWhole)

If Not rng is Nothing Then

    '[Rest of Code]

Else

   Msgbox myNum & "not found in Range"

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a formula.
Let's assume your number is in A1 and your list of numbers is in column D. You want the text in column E if you find the number in A1 within the list in Column D.

Normally you would just use `VLOOKUP()`.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,D:E,2,FALSE)
```

You can add a simple IF statement and `ISERROR()` to check if it succeeded in finding the number or not. Normally Excel will return "#N/A" if it was an error, but let's assume you want a message.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,D:E,2,FALSE)),"ERROR",VLOOKUP(A1,D:E,2,FALSE))
```